# Retrieving either indexed data or the last record in each group

Tags: mysql

There is a table `routes` that contains data as shown below:

```
Id   GroupID   TickID   Data
-------------------------
1    1         1        A
2    1         2        B
3    1         3        C
4    2         1        D
5    2         2        E
6    3         1        F
```

I have a PHP file where the user should be able to pass a "TickID", and than the script should return: For every GroupID the Data for the given TickID by the user, but if the user passes a TickID which is bigger than the maximum TickID in a certain GroupID, than the LAST row for that particular GroupID should be returned.

i.e.

UserInput, TickID 1, returns

```
Id   GroupID   TickID   Data
-------------------------
1    1         1        A
4    2         1        D
6    3         1        F
```

UserInput, TickID 3, returns

```
Id   GroupID   TickID   Data
-------------------------
3    1         3        C
5    2         2        E
6    3         1        F
```

I found how to select the "latest" row, i.e. the biggest TickID per GroupID with a good performance already here: [Retrieving the last record in each group - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql)

But I'm not sure how to combine it with a selection of rows inbetween.

**EDIT**
What I have right now is:
Make 3 queries:

1st query: Select biggest TickID for every group
`SELECT GroupID, MAX(TickID) maxTick From routes GROUP BY GroupID`

Than do two queries:
One for the GroupsIDs which do have a TickID entry in the database bigger than the userinput ->
`SELECT GroupID, Data From routes WHERE TickID = userTickID GROUP BY GroupID`

And do another query for the Groups which do not have a TickID as big as given by the user: Select the biggest TickIDs for those Groups.
Similarly to [Retrieving the last record in each group - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql)

Seems a big non-performant.
Any ideas to improve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would phrase your query as:

```
SELECT r1.*
FROM routes r1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT GroupID, MAX(TickID) AS MaxTickID
    FROM routes
    GROUP BY GroupID
) r2
    ON r1.GroupID = r2.GroupID AND
       (r1.TickID = userTickID OR
        (r1.TickID = r2.MaxTickID AND r2.MaxTickID < userTickID));
```

The logic here is a slight play on the canonical max per group join approach.  Here we take the `TickID` which is the max in the group only if the user tick ID be *greater* than the max.  Otherwise, we take the record whose `TickID` matches the input user value.

Adding the following index on `routes` should dramatically speed up the max subquery:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON routes (GroupID, TickID);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it. `t1` in the two last lines of the query should be `r1` I suppose :) And `t2` likewise :) But it seems to work. How to make it max. performant? Adding an index (GroupID, TickID) on the table?

Comment: @tim Check the updated answer.  Great first name, by the way, reminds me of myself `:-P`

Comment: Thanks, yes, I had this index. And the speed is great. Very good query, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is depended by data.

- (A) Are ids of TickID always continuous? e.g. TickID=1,2,3,4,5,6
- (B) May numbers be skipped in some cases? e.g. TickID=1,4,6

(A) the query is as follows.

```
select * from routes
  where (GroupID, TickID) in
    (select GroupID, max(TickID) from routes where TickID<=3 group by GroupID);
```

(B) the query is as follows.

```
with
MatchUserInput as (
  select GroupID, TickID from routes where TickID=3
),
MaxTickID as (
  select GroupID, max(TickID) from routes
    where GroupID not in (select GroupID from MatchUserInput) group by GroupID
)
select * from routes
where (GroupID, TickID) in (
  select * from MatchUserInput
  union select * from MaxTickID
);
```

Replace the above "3" with UserInput.